# Type-casting problem while building fluid interface

Tags: php, design-patterns, casting, phpstorm, intellisense

For example we have the following abstract class

```
<?php
    class AbstractClass {
        public function setParam(): AbstractClass {}
    }

    class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
        public function test():void {}
    }
```

When you'll try to use it like this

```
<?php
(new ConcreteClass())->setParam()->test();
```

Then after `setParam` we will see only `setParam` method, because `setParam` returns `AbstractClass`. I tried to mark `setParam` inside `AbsractClass` with PHP-doc `@return self`, but it doesn't work.

Are there any solutions of this problem?

Comment: @NigelRen I just wrote the code as small as possible. In full code there is `return $this` inside `setParam` You can see that return type of the `setParam` method is an `AbstractClass`. This code works well, but IDEA can't see `test` method after `setParam`, because `setParam` returns AbstractClass, and IDE helps you with only methods from `AbstractClass`.

Comment: The question isn't clear about the problem being in an IDE, which one are you using?

Comment: @NigelRen I'm using JetBrains PHPStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use `@return static` PHP-doc attribute

```
<?php

class A {
   /** @return static */
   public function methodA(): A;
}

class B {
   /** @return static */
   public function methodB(): B;
}

(new B())->methodB()->methodA()->methodB();
```

Everything in this example will be highlighted correctly.